# hibernate insert?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to learn hibernate and was wondering how to create a relationship with a one to many with an already existing many.

Do I first query the database to get the object of the many part of the relationship and then add this to a set on the one part?

thanks

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? Are you accessing it through JPA? Where's your code sample? Please put some more effort into this question.

Comment: Sorry no code sample just a general question after doing some reading on hibernate. I will be using the latest version. and yes through JPA. I looked at this http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/HibernateOnetoMany.shtml and wondered how the many part would work if it already existed.

Comment: Read up here - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqh.

Comment: Is it a one-to-many or many-to-many? Because you say the many side exists, so normally (not necessarily) there shall exist an object in one side too.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the id of the many side then

```
parent.getChilds().add(session.load<Child>(id));
```

which will create a proxy without goning to the db

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the two-sided mapping in hibernate. This allows you to add a value only to one side and will be there in the other side when you fetch.

e.g. Here you have a one-to-many relationship between `city` and `streets`

```
@Entity public class City {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="city")
    @OrderBy("streetName")
    public List<Street> getStreets() {
        return streets;
    }
...
}

@Entity public class Street {
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    ...
}
```

For more details, have a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#entity-mapping-association-collections).